# why customTableViewCell is different and slow?

Tags: ios, uitableview

in storyboard I set tableviewcell Identifier "firstCell" and class "FirstTableViewCell".
 In UIViewcontroller:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"firstCell";
   FirstTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier ];
   NSLog(@"%@",cell);
   if (cell == nil)
   {
       cell = (FirstTableViewCell *)[[FirstTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
   }
    return cell;
}
```

the output:

```
2013-09-12 20:30:10.378 InfoDrop[4120:c07] FirstTableViewCell: 0x75624b0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 44); layer = CALayer : 0x7562610    

2013-09-12 20:30:10.584 InfoDrop[4120:c07] FirstTableViewCell: 0x75624b0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 44); hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = CALayer: 0x7562610

2013-09-12 20:30:10.586 InfoDrop[4120:c07] <FirstTableViewCell: 0x8181a40; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x81a46e0>>

2013-09-12 21:18:08.042 InfoDrop[4415:c07] <FirstTableViewCell: 0x83993e0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x8398c90>>
```

why it's different? And you can see the time between the second cell and the first cell is bigger than the time between the third cell and the second time,why? thx.

@implementation FirstTableViewCell

in Cell:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
  self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
}
return self;
}
-(void)setCa:(Categories *)ca{

UILabel *nameLabelView = (UILabel *)[self.contentView viewWithTag:1];
nameLabelView.text=ca.name;

UILabel *detailLabelView = (UILabel *)[self.contentView viewWithTag:2];
detailLabelView.text=[ca.count stringValue];

UIView *left =(UIView *) [self.contentView viewWithTag:3];
UIView *fill;



int tmp = [ca.id intValue];

switch (tmp) {
    case 1:
        fill = [[CreditView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 27, 27)];         

        break;
    case 2:
        fill = [[BankView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 27, 27)];
        break;
    case 3:
        fill = [[QuestionView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 27, 27)];
        break;
    case 4:
        fill = [[SoftwareView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 27, 27)];
        break;
    case 5:
        fill = [[NoteView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 27, 27)];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

[left addSubview:fill];
[left setNeedsDisplay];
[nameLabelView setNeedsDisplay];
[detailLabelView setNeedsDisplay];

}

-(void)setcaNil:(int) sum {


UILabel *nameLabelView = (UILabel *)[self.contentView viewWithTag:1];
nameLabelView.text=@"All";

UILabel *detailLabelView = (UILabel *)[self.contentView viewWithTag:2];
detailLabelView.text=[[NSNumber numberWithInt:sum] stringValue];

UIView  *f =(UIView *) [self.contentView viewWithTag:3];

AllView * ui = [[AllView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 27, 27)];
[f addSubview:ui];


[f setNeedsDisplay];
[nameLabelView setNeedsDisplay];
[detailLabelView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: Does your `FirstTableViewCell` have a XIB file?

Comment: Paste your code from initWithStyle from this custom cell - what are you doing there ? From your output it looks like first two calls are using the cell (same memory address 0x75624b0) and the 3rd one is creating clean one. Do you have also prepareForReuse implemented in your class?

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski I paste part of cell's code. I don't have prepareForReuse. I put 2 UILabel and a uiview use storyboard.

Comment: @Amar no XIB file all in storyboard

Comment: Is it whole log output you got ? it's strange that first 2 cells are reused.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski there are 6 cells. first 2 cells' memory address are same. The others different

Comment: Are you using prototype cells or static? What you're doing in your cell class code isn't correct -- you shouldn't be adding any content to the cell there, that should be done in cellForRowAtIndexPath..

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest you to implement the method prepareForReuse in your FirstTableViewCell class.  In that method clean the all elements that can't be reused by the cell (Example: UILabel text values). I don't suggest recreating UIViews in this method because the performance ***might*** be affected.

But it's difficult giving a complete judgment without looking at the whole code in the execution stack related for this problem.

**Update**
Based on your code update, I suggest you to do the following

```
//In your .h cell file

@property(nonatomic,strong)UILabel *nameLabelView
@property(nonatomic,strong)UILabel *detailLabelView
@property(nonatomic,strong)UIView *leftView

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier

  self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
  if (self) {
      // Initialization code
      //Here initialize your uilabels and uiview using CGRectZero as frame
      self.leftView = [UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0.0,27.0,27.0)];
      [self.contentView addSubview:self.leftView];
  }
  return self;

  -(void)prepareForReuse
  {
    //clean up the text values for your labels
  }

 -(void)setCa:(Categories *)ca{
    UILabel *nameLabelView = (UILabel *)[self.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    nameLabelView.text=ca.name;

    UILabel *detailLabelView = (UILabel *)[self.contentView viewWithTag:2];
    detailLabelView.text=[ca.count stringValue];
    UIView *fill;
    switch (tmp) {
      case 1:
      fill = [[CreditView alloc]init];         
       break;
       case 2:
       fill = [[BankView alloc]init];
       break;
       case 3:
       fill = [[QuestionView alloc]init];
       break;
       case 4:
       fill = [[SoftwareView alloc]init];
       break;
       case 5:
       fill = [[NoteView alloc]init];
       break;
       default:
       break;
    }
        [self.lefView addSubview:fill];
        //BTW this code has a lot of potential for a good refactoring
 }

 -(void)layoutSubViews{
      self.leftView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,27.0,27.0);
      //Do the rest of positioning for your elements here
 }
```

For this case calling:

```
[left setNeedsDisplay];
[nameLabelView setNeedsDisplay];
[detailLabelView setNeedsDisplay];
```

Is overkill because you force to the system to redraw your views. Instead do your positioning in the layoutSubviews, which is called by your uiTableViewController everytime that the cell will appears in your table.

Comment: the leftview doesn't appear. this method (initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier: ) doesn't load .